# Using dynamic variables in $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

How to use dynamic deferred's inside $.when? Got one function `ajaxFunction` which returns deferred promise.

```
function ajaxFunction(image){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    //Ajax of image
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

calling this ajaxFunction based on dynamic condition like

```
var defs = {};
var someQuerySelector = document.querySelectorAll('image');
for (var i = 0; i < someQuerySelector.length; i++) {
    defs[d + 'i'] = ajaxFunction(someQuerySelector[i]);
}
```

Now I want to use these into `$.when()` how to use `defs` dynamic keys inside like `$.when(defs['d1'],defs['d2'])`. How to use dynamic variables into this. Any change in approach or help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `defs` to an array you can `apply()` it to `$.when`, like this:

```
var defs = [];
var someQuerySelector = document.querySelectorAll('image');
for (var i = 0; i < someQuerySelector.length; i++){
  defs.push(ajaxFunction(someQuerySelector[i]));
}

$.when.apply(this, defs).done(function() {
    // all complete, do something...
});
```

Or purely in jQuery:

```
var defs = $('image').map(function() {
    return ajaxFunction(this);
});

$.when.apply(this, defs).done(function() {
    // all complete, do something...
});
```

The above is assuming that you change `image` to a valid selector, and that you're providing some parameters to your `ajaxFunction()`, otherwise repeatedly calling it the same way N times is pretty redundant.

Comment: yes I am using image as parameter. Updated the question also

Comment: $.when.apply(null, defs) this worked for me :) Thanks for your help